# Image.select: Pattern 'b2' did not match any bands

Tags: javascript, random-forest, google-earth-engine

I wanted to perform above-ground biomass prediction with random forest algorithm. I am following a tutorial but I want to import my own dataset as a predictor. This is what I tried so far:

```
//adding the biomass map 
var biomass  = ee.Image('users/gulnihalkurtt/biomass');
var biomass_2020 = biomass.clip(boundary)
var biomass_20201 = biomass_2020.select('b1').rename('b2')
var visualization = {bands: ['b2'],};
Map.addLayer(biomass_20201, visualization, "biomass");
///////////////////
```

I wanted to rename the band as b2 so that I can include the raster in the algorithm like this:

```
// Bands to include in the classification
var bands = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'B11', 'B12', 'VV_iqr', 'VH_iqr', 'elevation', 'slope','b1','b2'];
```

But I get an error which says: Line 238: Image.select: Pattern 'b2' did not match any bands.

Here is my full script:

```
// Load Sentinel-1 for the post-rainy season.
var S1_PRS = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
    .filterDate('2020-04-01', '2020-06-30')
    .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VH'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'ASCENDING'))
    .filterBounds(boundary);

// Prepare inter-quartile range (IQR) 
var S1_PRS_pc = S1_PRS.reduce(ee.Reducer.percentile([25,50,75]));

// Convert to natural units (linear units, which can be averaged)
var S1_PRS_pc = ee.Image(10).pow(S1_PRS_pc.divide(10));

var S1_PRS_pc_Feats = S1_PRS_pc.select(['VH_p50','VV_p50']).clip(boundary);

// Reproject to WGS 84 UTM zone 35s                
var S1_PRS_pc_Feats = S1_PRS_pc_Feats.reproject({crs: 'EPSG:32735',scale: 100}); 
  
// Check projection information
print('Projection, crs, and crs_transform:', S1_PRS_pc_Feats.projection());    

// Calculate inter-quartile range (IQR), a measure of Sentinel-1 backscatter variability
var PRS_VV_iqr = S1_PRS_pc_Feats.addBands((S1_PRS_pc.select('VV_p75').subtract(S1_PRS_pc.select('VV_p25'))).rename('VV_iqr'));
var PRS_VH_iqr = S1_PRS_pc_Feats.addBands((S1_PRS_pc.select('VH_p75').subtract(S1_PRS_pc.select('VH_p25'))).rename('VH_iqr'));

// Print the image to the console
print('Post-rainy Season VV IQR', PRS_VV_iqr);
// Print the image to the console
print('Post-rainy Season VV IQR', PRS_VH_iqr);

// Display S1 inter-quartile range imagery
Map.addLayer(PRS_VV_iqr.clip(boundary), {'bands': 'VV_iqr', min: 0,max: 0.1}, 'Sentinel-1 IW VV');
Map.addLayer( PRS_VH_iqr.clip(boundary), {'bands': 'VH_iqr', min: 0,max: 0.1}, 'Sentinel-1 IW VH');

/////////////////////
// Load Sentinel-2 spectral reflectance data.
var s2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR');

// Create a function to mask clouds using the Sentinel-2 QA band.
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');

  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(10).int();
  var cirrusBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(11).int();

  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0).and(
             qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));

  // Return the masked and scaled data.
  return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

// Filter clouds from Sentinel-2 for a given period.
var composite = s2.filterDate('2020-04-01', '2020-06-30')
                  // Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules.
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
                  .map(maskS2clouds)
                  .select('B2', 'B3', 'B4','B5','B6','B7','B8','B11', 'B12'); 

// Reproject to WGS 84 UTM zone 35s                  
var S2_composite = composite.median().reproject({crs: 'EPSG:32635', scale: 100});

// Check projection information                 
print('Projection, crs, and crs_transform:', S2_composite.projection());

// Display a composite S2 imagery
Map.addLayer(S2_composite.clip(boundary), {bands: ['B11', 'B8', 'B3'], min: 0, max: 0.3});

//////////////////
// Load SRTM
var SRTM = ee.Image("USGS/SRTMGL1_003");
// Clip Elevation
var elevation = SRTM.clip(boundary);

// Reproject 'elevation' to WGS 84 UTM zone 35s                
var elevation = elevation.reproject({crs: 'EPSG:32635',scale: 100}); 
  
// Check projection information
print('Projection, crs, and crs_transform:', elevation.projection()); 

// Derive slope from the SRTM
var slope = ee.Terrain.slope(SRTM).clip(boundary);

// Reproject 'slope' to WGS 84 UTM zone 35s                
var slope = slope.reproject({crs: 'EPSG:32635',scale: 100}); 
  
// Check projection information
print('Projection, crs, and crs_transform:', slope.projection()); 

// Adding soil map
var soil  = ee.Image('users/gulnihalkurtt/btg').clip(boundary);
//soil = soil.addBands ('b1')
var soil = soil.reproject({crs: 'EPSG:32635',scale: 100});

var visualization = {bands: ['b1'],};

Map.addLayer(soil, visualization, "Soil");


// Extracting the forest areas
var siniflama  = ee.Image('users/gulnihalkurtt/siniflama_bmh1');

// Clip the land cover to the boundary
var LC_2020 = siniflama.clip(boundary);

// Extract forest areas from the land cover
var forest_mask = LC_2020.updateMask(
  LC_2020.eq(77) // Only keep pixels where class equals 77
);

// Display forests only
var visualization = {bands: ['b1'],};

Map.addLayer(forest_mask, visualization, "Trees");

//adding the biomass map 
var biomass  = ee.Image('users/gulnihalkurtt/biomass');
var biomass_2020 = biomass.clip(boundary)
var biomass_20201 = biomass_2020.select('b1').rename('b2')
var visualization = {bands: ['b2'],};
Map.addLayer(biomass_20201, visualization, "biomass");
///////////////////
// Merge the predictor variables
var mergedCollection = S2_composite.addBands(PRS_VV_iqr.addBands(PRS_VH_iqr.addBands(elevation.addBands(slope.addBands(forest_mask.addBands(soil))))));

// Clip to the output image to Harare study area boundary.
var clippedmergedCollection = mergedCollection.clipToCollection(boundary);
print('clippedmergedCollection: ', clippedmergedCollection);
//Map.addLayer(clippedmergedCollection, {bands: ['B8', 'B4', 'B3'], max: 0.3}, 'mergedCollection');

// Bands to include in the classification
var bands = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B8', 'B11', 'B12', 'VV_iqr', 'VH_iqr', 'elevation', 'slope','b1','b2'];

////////////////////
// Prepare training dataset
// More information at https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LARSE_GEDI_GEDI04_B_002

var l4b = ee.Image('LARSE/GEDI/GEDI04_B_002');

var dataset = l4b.select('MU').clip(boundary);
Map.setCenter(28.8713,-18.4492, 12);

// Reproject to WGS 84 UTM zone 35s                  
var dataset = dataset.reproject({crs: 'EPSG:32635', scale: 200});

// Check projection information                 
print('Projection, crs, and crs_transform:', dataset.projection());

// Display the GEDI L4B dataset
Map.addLayer(dataset,
    {min: 10, max: 250, palette: '440154,414387,2a788e,23a884,7ad151,fde725'},
    'Mean Biomass');

// Sample the training points from the dataset
var points = dataset.sample({
   region: boundary,
   scale: 200,
   numPixels: 1000, 
   geometries: true});

// Print and display the points derived from the GEDI L4B dataset
print(points.size());
print(points.limit(10));

Map.addLayer(points);

// Split training data into training and testing sets 
// Add a random column (named random) and specify the seed value for repeatability
var datawithColumn = points.randomColumn('random', 300);

// Use 70% for training, 30% for validation
var split = 0.7; 
var trainingData = datawithColumn.filter(ee.Filter.lt('random', split));
print('training data', trainingData);

var validationData = datawithColumn.filter(ee.Filter.gte('random', split));
print('validation data', validationData);

////////////////////
// Perform random forest regression

// Collect training data
var training = clippedmergedCollection.select(bands).sampleRegions({
  collection: trainingData,
  properties: ['MU'],
  scale: 200 // Need to change the scale of training data to avoid the 'out of memory' problem
  });

// Train a random forest classifier for regression 
var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(150)
  .setOutputMode('REGRESSION')
  .train({
    features: training, 
    classProperty: "MU",
    inputProperties: bands
    });

//Run the classification and clip it to the boundary
var regression = clippedmergedCollection.select(bands).classify(classifier, 'predicted').clip(boundary);

// Load and define a continuous palette
var palettes = require('users/gena/packages:palettes');

// Choose and define a palette
var palette = palettes.colorbrewer.YlGn[5];

// Display the input imagery and the regression classification.
  // get dictionaries of min & max predicted value
  var regressionMin = (regression.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.min(),
    scale: 100, 
    crs: 'EPSG:32635',
    geometry: boundary,
    bestEffort: true,
    tileScale: 16
  }));
  
  var regressionMax = (regression.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
    scale: 100, 
    crs: 'EPSG:32635',
    geometry: boundary,
    bestEffort: true,
    tileScale: 16
  }));
  
// Add to map
var viz = {palette: palette, min: regressionMin.getNumber('predicted').getInfo(), max: regressionMax.getNumber('predicted').getInfo()};
Map.addLayer(regression, viz, 'Regression');

// Create the panel for the legend items.
var legend = ui.Panel({
  style: {
    position: 'bottom-left',
    padding: '8px 15px'
  }
});

// Create and add the legend title.
var legendTitle = ui.Label({
  value: 'AGBD (Mg/ha)',
  style: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: '18px',
    margin: '0 0 4px 0',
    padding: '0'
  }
});

legend.add(legendTitle);

// create the legend image
var lon = ee.Image.pixelLonLat().select('latitude');
var gradient = lon.multiply((viz.max-viz.min)/100.0).add(viz.min);
var legendImage = gradient.visualize(viz);
 
// create text on top of legend
var panel = ui.Panel({
widgets: [
ui.Label(viz['max'])
],
});
 
legend.add(panel);
 
// create thumbnail from the image
var thumbnail = ui.Thumbnail({
image: legendImage,
params: {bbox:'0,0,10,100', dimensions:'10x200'},
style: {padding: '1px', position: 'bottom-center'}
});
 
// add the thumbnail to the legend
legend.add(thumbnail);
 
// create text on top of legend
var panel = ui.Panel({
widgets: [
ui.Label(viz['min'])
],
});

legend.add(panel);
Map.add(legend);

// Zoom to the regression on the map
Map.centerObject(boundary, 11);

//////////////////////////
// Check model performance
// Get details of classifier
var classifier_details = classifier.explain();

// Explain the classifier with importance values
var variable_importance = ee.Feature(null, ee.Dictionary(classifier_details).get('importance'));

var chart =
  ui.Chart.feature.byProperty(variable_importance)
  .setChartType('ColumnChart')
  .setOptions({
  title: 'Random Forest Variable Importance',
  legend: {position: 'none'},
  hAxis: {title: 'Bands'},
  vAxis: {title: 'Importance'}
});

// Plot a chart
print("Variable importance:", chart);

// Create model assessment statistics
// Get predicted regression points in same location as training data
var predictedTraining = regression.sampleRegions({collection:trainingData, geometries: true});

// Separate the observed (agbd_GEDI) and predicted (regression) properties
var sampleTraining = predictedTraining.select(['MU', 'predicted']);

// Create chart, print it
var chartTraining = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(sampleTraining, 'MU', 'predicted')
.setChartType('ScatterChart').setOptions({
title: 'Predicted vs Observed - Training data ',
hAxis: {'title': 'observed'},
vAxis: {'title': 'predicted'},
pointSize: 3,
trendlines: { 0: {showR2: true, visibleInLegend: true} ,
1: {showR2: true, visibleInLegend: true}}});
print(chartTraining);

// Compute Root Mean Squared Error (RMSE)
// Get array of observation and prediction values 
var observationTraining = ee.Array(sampleTraining.aggregate_array('MU'));

var predictionTraining = ee.Array(sampleTraining.aggregate_array('predicted'));

// Compute residuals
var residualsTraining = observationTraining.subtract(predictionTraining);

// Compute RMSE with equation and print the result
var rmseTraining = residualsTraining.pow(2).reduce('mean', [0]).sqrt();
print('Training RMSE', rmseTraining);

/////////////////////
//Perform validation
// Get predicted regression points in same location as validation data
var predictedValidation = regression.sampleRegions({collection:validationData, geometries: true});

// Separate the observed (MU) and predicted (regression) properties
var sampleValidation = predictedValidation.select(['MU', 'predicted']);

// Create chart and print it
var chartValidation = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(sampleValidation, 'predicted', 'MU')
.setChartType('ScatterChart').setOptions({
title: 'Predicted vs Observed - Validation data',
hAxis: {'title': 'predicted'},
vAxis: {'title': 'observed'},
pointSize: 3,
trendlines: { 0: {showR2: true, visibleInLegend: true} ,
1: {showR2: true, visibleInLegend: true}}});
print(chartValidation);

// Compute RMSE
// Get array of observation and prediction values 
var observationValidation = ee.Array(sampleValidation.aggregate_array('MU'));

var predictionValidation = ee.Array(sampleValidation.aggregate_array('predicted'));

// Compute residuals
var residualsValidation = observationValidation.subtract(predictionValidation);

// Compute RMSE with equation and print it
var rmseValidation = residualsValidation.pow(2).reduce('mean', [0]).sqrt();
print('Validation RMSE', rmseValidation);

//////////////////
// Export the image, specifying scale and region.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: regression,
  description: 'Muf_AGBD_GEDI_2021',
  scale: 20,
  crs: 'EPSG:32635', // EPSG:32735 (WGS 84 UTM Zone 35S)
  maxPixels: 6756353855,
  region: boundary
});
```

Comment: Note: Java != Javascript - this seems to be JS only

Comment: The code you've quoted doesn't exhibit the problem, and your link is not shared publicly so I can't view your full code. Can you please work on [producing a short sample which is runnable to demonstrate the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? This will help us identify the problem and answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Band names are case-sensitive, so you'll need to be consistent and use "B2" here (instead of "b2").